# Angle between space diagonal in a cube?

Tags: math, geometry, cube

Wondering if the angle between two space diagonals of a cube, which are lying in one plane have always the same angle. 
I have now calculated a lot but become somehow confused and cant get a definite answer.

Comment: Possibly try: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This isn't a Mathematica question. It might be a math question. Maybe it's something you can work out in Mathematica, but that implementation isn't what the OP has asked for.

Comment: Thank you...now i see it. I thought it says mathematics. I am going to change it now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any pair of space diagonals lies in rectangular section of cube, and this rectangle has edges A and A * Sqrt(2), where A = cube edge length. So the angle between two space diagonals of a cube is always the same (ArcCos(1/3))